# setCustomAnimations not working on back button press

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I've got this issue where transitions from fragment A to B working fine but on backPress they do not. Looking around I saw many with this issue but none of the answers seems to help me out. I must be doing something wrong but have no idea what and I would love some help, it drives me nuts!

This is my logic:

**Fragment A calling fragment B:**

```
private void loadNextFragment(WeatherComplete[] weatherDataArrayList) {

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

MainFragment mf = MainFragment.newInstance();
mf.setVars(choosenCity, weatherDataArrayList);
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_iout, R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_iout);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.replace(R.id.frame, mf);
ft.commit();
```

}

**Fragment B calling fragment C (Settings) from menu:**

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_settings:
                final FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_iout, R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_iout);
                ft.replace(R.id.frame, new Settings(), "settings");
                ft.commit();
                break;
```

I'm passing an object array from fragment A to fragment B, thus when clicking the back button on fragment C it will go back to fragment B but there is no object array to work with so in that case I want fragment C to go back to fragment A instead - I'm popping the backStack:

```
        if (weatherDataObj == null) {

            Log.d(TAG, "WEATHER DATA IS NULL");

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
//            ft.remove(this);
            ft.commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this:

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_iout,
        R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_iout);
```

Comment: That fixed it but I've tried it many times just not in the right place! 

When I see this line - ft.addToBackStack(null);  does this mean the fragment that I'm NOW ADDING will be added to the backstack or does it mean the CURRENTLY VISIBLE fragment will be added?

I'm getting weird behaviors all over my app with the back button

Comment: @Yosi199 addToBackStack(null) means the fragment transaction you are applying this on will be saved and made reversable. It can be actions with multiple fragments.

Comment: would u mind having a look at the video I've posted here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pa0WK2ZQP2Y&feature=youtu.be

Comment: It shows me going from fragment A to B and then to C. Then in fragment C clicking the back button will take me back to fragment B but I'm checking for null - if it's null then I'm calling popBackStack() which takes me back to fragment A. All is good so far but when I'm back to fragment A I again go to fragment B and back button ago now gives me fragment C! it shows in the video. any ideas?

Comment: @Yosi199 need to see the code of all fragment transactions and also code of the *null check* (no idea what you meant).

Comment: I've edited the post with relevant code. let me know if you need more info and thank you for your help it is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: @Yosi199 try to add the B to C transaction to the back stack.